# Glide listener is not working to hide progressbar after loading image

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-glide

I'm trying to hide the progress bar after loading image using Glide.But Glide.listener() is not working.Please find the codes below.

```
 @BindingAdapter({
                "bind:url"
        })
        public void setImage(ImageView imageView, String url) {
            if (url != null && url.trim().length() > 0) {
                     Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load("http://" + url)
                        .override(200, 150)
                        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                bindFamilyMembers.imagebar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                bindFamilyMembers.imagebar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.bg_theme)
                        .error(R.drawable.bg_theme)
                        .into(imageView);
                //    Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load("http://" + url).resize(200, 150).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).into(imageView);
            } else  {

            }
        }
```

the layout of this code is below.Im using data-binding in my app .I have tried to set visibility as Gone using data-binding but its not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="familyhandler"
            type="com.estuate.smartfoam.dashboard.model.apiuser.FamilyMembers" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <com.estuate.smartfoam.util.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/member_image"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/linear_margin_10"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:url="@{familyhandler.image}" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/border"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@drawable/circular_img_selected" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{familyhandler.fullname}"
                android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/member_image"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16"
                tools:text="Name"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/imagebar"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@xml/progress"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/adding_view"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/linear_margin_15"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_material"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_add" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I have used Glide to parse image.but not able to stop the progress bar.can you help me fix this issue .

Comment: @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.imageView.invalidate();//add this line
                        return false;
                    }

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug with ImageView's visibility if it's invisible or gone. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/618